# Javascript: how can I use link to image in my object, created by toDataURL, instead of placing data to every screen element

Tags: javascript, image, background, todataurl

Before creating tree I use canvas to draw some icons (plus, minus, node. etc.). Then I put images to object and stop using canvas. Like this:

```
var imgFromCnvs = NewElem.toDataURL("image/png");
var ElemIdName = 'treeVLineLast';
treeEl.imgs[ElemIdName]=imgFromCnvs
```

Then I use them in background images on the tree:

```
NewElem.style.backgroundImage = 'url("'+treeEl.imgs.treeVLineLast+'")';
```

So, as I understand, it extremely enlarges data amount on page, because I place data from object strictly to every element instead of using link to it. Since there can be hundreds or even thousands tree elements in a tree, it will cause some memory issues, I think.

I guess, it could be the best way to use link to data in the object somehow, but I do not know how. May be, create some new element?
Is there any way to solve this problem?

P.S.: I'm learning JavaScript and need to understand the basics **without using any libraries**.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but why don't you just use css for displaying icons like plus, minus, node etc. ? Take a look at e.g [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

Comment: @msohns: I need to know how to use links to images created with toDataURL method and stored in objects (instead of placing data to plenty elements plenty times).